# Get PopUp Message From Alert in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I need some advice or tip for this issue that i have.

I have a script that log-in in a page using puppeteer, i need capture the login if was correctly or if was wrong the message from the alert, but when i made click on send button, this open a new window with an alert, and i can't capture.

I've using some methods from other answer in this place, like capture the popup event or targetcreated event,

```
//const newPagePromise = new Promise( tab => page.once('popup', tab) );
//const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
```

but not works for me.

The code below is that i'm using it for this purpose. This project uses puppeteer 5.2.1

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    //Login RBM page
    await page.goto('http://www.rbmtest.com.co/AdminMenuMonWeb/pages/welcome/Login.jsp', { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });

    try {
// with this lines, i've try to capture the event for the new window opened
        // const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.on('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
        const newPagePromise = new Promise( tab => page.once('popup', tab) );
        //type user and password wrong
        await page.type('#login', 'jhonsmith');
        await page.type('#password', 'France5523*!');
// with this lines i've try to work using differents ways to click on button and capture the event
        // await page.click('input[name="b1"]', { clickCount: 1, delay: 200 });
        // const link = await page.$('input[name="b1"]');
        // await link.click();
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector("input[name='b1']").click();
        });
        const popup = await newPagePromise;
                let msgWrong = ''
        await popup.on("dialog", async (dialog) => {
            console.log(dialog.message());
            msgWrong = dialog.message();
            await dialog.accept();
        });

       if ( msgWrong ) {
            //put info on database
            await popup.close();
       } else {
            await popup.waitForXPath('//*[@id="as_cssmenu"]/ul/li[1]/a', { timeout: 5000 });
            // put login correct on database
            await popup.close();
       }
        
        await page.close();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await page.close();

    }

    await browser.close();

})();
```

Any advice is welcome.

Regards!!

Comment: The suggestions are good. You're awaiting things that aren't promises, like `page.on`, which does nothing.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen i've try to use // const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.on('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));

And const newPagePromise = new Promise( tab => page.once('popup', tab) );

But still not work for me....